# Python Pandas - Time Series Find Index of Previous Row

Tags: python, pandas

I am analyzing time series data of one stock to seek the highest price for further analysis, here is the sample dataframe `df`:

```
   date      close   high_3days
2021-05-01    20        20
2021-05-02    23        23
2021-05-03    26        26
2021-05-04    24        26
2021-05-05    20        26
2021-05-06    26        26
2021-05-07    22        26
2021-05-08    30        30
2021-05-09    20        30
2021-05-10    20        30
```

I want to add a new column to **find the number of days from previous 3 days high**. My logic is seeking the index of the row of previous high, and then subtract it from the index of current row.

Here is the desire output:

```
   date      close   high_3days  days_previous_high
2021-05-01    20        20               0
2021-05-02    23        23               0
2021-05-03    26        26               0
2021-05-04    24        26               1
2021-05-05    20        26               2
2021-05-06    22        26               3
2021-05-07    20        26               4
2021-05-08    30        30               0
2021-05-09    20        30               1
2021-05-10    20        30               2
```

Could you help to figure the way out~? Thanks guys!

Comment: Why do the values in `close` and `high_3days` change?

Comment: @HenryEcker Thanks for reminder! I've corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a boolean index with [`expanding max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.expanding.Expanding.max.html#pandas-core-window-expanding-expanding-max), then enumerate each group with [`groupby cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-cumcount):

```
df['days_previous_high'] = df.groupby(
    df['high_3days'].expanding().max().diff().gt(0).cumsum()).cumcount()
```

`df`:

```
         date  close  high_3days  days_previous_high
0  2021-05-01     20          20                   0
1  2021-05-02     23          23                   0
2  2021-05-03     26          26                   0
3  2021-05-04     24          26                   1
4  2021-05-05     20          26                   2
5  2021-05-06     22          26                   3
6  2021-05-07     20          26                   4
7  2021-05-08     30          30                   0
8  2021-05-09     20          30                   1
9  2021-05-10     20          30                   2
```

---

Explaination:

[`expanding max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.expanding.Expanding.max.html#pandas-core-window-expanding-expanding-max) is used to determine the current maximum value at each row.

```
df['high_3days'].expanding().max()
```

[`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html#pandas-series-diff) can be used to see where the current value exceeds the max.

```
df['high_3days'].expanding().max().diff()
```

groups can be created by taking the [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html#pandas-series-cumsum) of where the diff is greater than 0:

```
df['high_3days'].expanding().max().diff().gt(0).cumsum()
```

```
expanding_max  expanding_max_diff  expanding_max_gt_0  expanding_max_gt_0_cs
         20.0                 NaN               False                      0
         23.0                 3.0                True                      1
         26.0                 3.0                True                      2
         26.0                 0.0               False                      2
         26.0                 0.0               False                      2
         26.0                 0.0               False                      2
         26.0                 0.0               False                      2
         30.0                 4.0                True                      3
         30.0                 0.0               False                      3
         30.0                 0.0               False                      3
```

Now that rows are grouped, [`groupby cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-cumcount) can be used to enumerate each group:

```
df.groupby(df['high_3days'].expanding().max().diff().gt(0).cumsum()).cumcount()
```

```
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    2
5    3
6    4
7    0
8    1
9    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Awesome! It works for me. Thanks for the detailed elaboration on those pandas function. This is my first time to use `cumsum()` and `cumcount()`